# How to connect thermostat to this furnace?

Tags: thermostat, furnace

I have an oil burning Brock EliteAir furnace, it has 2 wires Tw and Tr on the burner section going to the thermostat. BUT there are C Y G R wires on the side ( where there's a fan logo) that are not connected to anything.
Now my furnace works but the fan stays on all the time.

How to make use of those C Y G R wires to connect them to my thermostat to control the fan or at least make it turn on and off with the heat.

I also broke my old thermostat while trying to connect the wires just matching the letters, so does any thermostat work? does google nest work? do I need a relay? so much research only made me more confused tbh. [image: right side wires]
[image: under access panel]

[image: old thermostat 1]

[image: old thermostat 2]

[image: schema]

[image: Top of burner]

[image: overview]

[image: inside]

[image: side wires]

Comment: show us the old thermostat

Comment: Nest works with 24 volt circuits. R is your 24 volt, C-is common, G is Fan, Y is cooling. The Tv and Tr are for your heating only thermostat.

Comment: Can you post photos of the furnace's wiring diagram, or a model number for that matter?

Comment: @ruskes Thanks guys, I posted old thermostat pics, and for the model number of the furnace it is  Brock MBP1-A, couldn't find much info, manual is easy to find but didn't know how to extract the information I need from. I posted the schema I found online although I can't find it on my actual furnace. I ordered a google nest thermostat from Amazon it will arrive tomorrow, any suggestion what setup I should try first, the nest has Y C W  G R ob -

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  posted them thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Any thermostat that supports a two-transformer system *should* work...

As long as you have five or more wires in your thermostat cable, you should be able to get most thermostats that support two-transformer systems to run your furnace without issue.  Simply wire Rh and W to the oil burner's Tw & Tr terminals, then connect Rc, C, and G to the R, C, and G terminals on the furnace's terminal block, respectively, then configure the thermostat for two-transformer operation (this may require removing a jumper or sliding a switch on the back of the thermostat).

### ...but your Nest is crippled to the point of *not supporting two-transformer systems*

However, you have a Nest E, which is an "el cheapo" version of the Nest that omits the extra terminals and switching needed to support two-transformer HVAC systems like yours *at all*.  So, you'll need to send it back and get a full-fledged Nest 3, or some other smart thermostat for that matter.

### As to that Ecobee...

Your Beckett control seems to have circuitry in the control path that the Ecobee's output circuit isn't expecting to see; this was never a problem for a bimetal thermostat since those are dumb switches, but the Ecobee is probably using a solid-state output circuit that's getting tripped up by whatever your control is doing.

As a result, you'll need to use a relay-transformer combination such as the Resideo/Honeywell RA89A1074.  For that specific device, you'll want to remove the supplied jumper, then connect 1 and 2 to a 120V supply inside the furnace, 3 and 4 to Tw & Tr on the burner control, and T/T to Rh and W from the thermostat.  That way, the Ecobee can be not-confused by the control's internal circuitry, as the relay simply acts as a "dumb switch".

Comment: Some Nests have a "parasitic" mode where they leech a little power off the signal wires during demand for heat/cool.  It's hit or miss whether that works with any given logic board, and I don't know if the Nest E is one of the thermostats that can do this.  It's not well documented.  It's worth a shot.

Comment: @jay613 -- the issue is that the Nest E can't deal with the fact that the W terminal needs to be connected to a *different* R terminal than the rest of the thermostat is using when it puts out a call for heat :P

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel thank you, I tried fiddling with the nest it can only turn fan on and off, never turned the burner on. I don't have to use nest, so can you please give me an example of a thermostat that supports two transformer system so I can buy it . thanks!

Comment: @Moussa -- the Nest 3 (not E) should do the job -- most Ecobees I believe have two-transformer support, as well as the Honeywell smart 'stats

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel just received the latest ecobbe from costco and tried the method you suggested  :( wire Rh and W to the oil burner's Th & Tr terminals, then connect Rc, C, and G to the R, C, and G terminals on the furnace's terminal block ) but it doesn't work, the thermostat powers on, fan control works, but no heat ( burner doesn't turn on and ecobee says mode "off" and can't change to on... I read on another thread someone suggesting a relay, you think a relay is needed?

Comment: @Moussa -- can you get me a photo showing the entire top label on your oil burner control please? (it's the box with the Tw and Tr terminals on it)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Hey I added few more pictures. What I got is that if I short Tr and Tw the boiler turns on. And there is 26 Volts between R and C. there are 3 wires going from the side panel to the burner , white wire going to L2 , red wire going to LIMIT, and green one going to a screw in the box maybe be ground.

Comment: @Moussa -- that's very strange that the Ecobee you have doesn't handle this situation correctly, as your burner control says in its [manual](https://www.beckettcorp.com/wp-content/uploads/61649-GeniSys-7505-Control-Manual.pdf) that it uses 24VAC at the thermostat terminals.  I wouldn't touch the rest of the wiring on that control, though.  As a sidenote, which model of Ecobee did you get?  [Ecobee's support docs](https://support.ecobee.com/s/articles/I-have-two-separate-R-wires-on-my-thermostat-what-do-I-need-to-know-about-my-ecobee-thermostat-installation) say that it's Rc/C paired...

Comment: you mean only use the Tr and Tw to wire the thermostat? that was the case before but the fan was always on there was no control over the fan . I got this Ecobee from costco : ecobee Smart Thermostat with voice control with Smart Sensor
Model  EB-STATES5C-01

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel forgot to tag you in the above comment.

Comment: @Moussa -- Tr and Tw are the only terminals *on the burner control* that should be touched.  Your model of Ecobee should support two-transformer systems based on the specs -- only thing I can think of is that the Beckett control puts the thermostat connections on the "low side" of the circuitry in the burner control, which is confusing the Ecobee's circuits, and would require you to fit a transformer-relay module to work around it.  I'd at least talk to Ecobee support at some point during this just to make sure you don't have a dead Ecobee

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Ecobee support are wankers, I'm not married to the Ecobee I will get any stat that works.. today ill pass by homedepot and get an older model with batteries and see.. but in any case thanks a lot for the input and support you've been very helpful. in case I got it working ill post the resolution